# Url not complying to .htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with one of the url's in my website , it doesn't seem to comply to my .htaccess rules. The problem I'm experiencing is the following.

I access my site using url: http://www.website.com/sitemap

I have the following .htaccess rules:

```
ReWriteEngine On

php_value include_path ".:/Webserver/blabla/boo"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms[A-Za-z0-9\-_/]*$
ReWriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-_/]*)$ /site/index.php/
ReWriteRule ^$ /site/index.php/
```

So I would expect this URL call to rewrite to /site/index.php but the point is it never goes there and instead opens sitemap.xml which is in the webroot. It does work for all other URL's in my site. What could be the case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. It was due to the MultiViews option set in httpd.conf and each individual site .conf file. I disabled the MultiViews option in the per site .conf file setting it to `-MultiViews`

Maybe this question fits better in Serverfault. Is there a posibility for me to transfer it?